# Erro ao executar projeto no Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, exceção, debug

Quando executo um projeto no Visual Studio apresenta o seguinte erro:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Código

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Logar
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string conexao = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Cadastro;User ID=sa;Password=m4st3r!";
            SqlConnection add = new SqlConnection(conexao);
            SqlCommand comado = new SqlCommand("select count (*) Usuario where Usuario =@user and Senha=@senha", add);

            comado.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
            comado.Parameters.Add("@senha", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox2.Text;

            add.Open();
            int i = (int) comado.ExecuteScalar();
            if (i > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Login e senha encontrado");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Erro");
            }
            add.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Que erro é este?

Comment: Você tentou continuar a execução para ver se acontece algo mais? Isto costuma acontecer como um aviso de que algo está errado mas ainda pode executar.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 3):

Esta mensagem está mostrando que houve uma exceção mas ela foi manipulada pelo componente que você está usando. Na maioria das vezes você não precisa fazer nada e isto não vai acontecer quando não estiver *debugando* a aplicação. É só um aviso e você pode continuar a execução sem problemas.

É possível desativar isto no Visual Studio. Algumas formas de fazer isto:

- Clicando com o botão direito na `Output Window` desmarque `Exception Messages`. ([Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60765/221800))
- Existe uma configuração no menu `Debug > Exceptions`. Abra `Common Language Runtime Exceptions`, depois `System` e desmarque `user-handled` das exceções que não quer que seja mostrado. ([Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13086139/221800))

[Blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20190124182513/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidklinems/archive/2005/07/12/438061.aspx) que explica melhor o funcionamento deste tipo de mensagem.

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente a mensagem de erro não convencional seja causada pelo problema apontado pelo @Maniero, mas há um problema na sua *query*:

```
select count (*) Usuario where Usuario =@user and Senha=@senha
```

Faltando a cláusula `from`

```
select count (*) from Usuario where Usuario =@user and Senha=@senha
```

Comment: Realmente estava faltando o from, muito obrigada! =)